# OS X "service" for running JavaScript bookmarklets in any app?

Tags: macos, javascript, bookmarklet, services

I have some JavaScript [bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) that work on the selected text in a web page, but I'd like to be able to use them on the selected text in *any* Mac OS X app, not just browsers or things that provide browser-like views. Mac OS X has the "Services" (sub)menu where any app can publish services that it can provide to other apps, but I don't know how to make my bookmarklets show up as services there.

Is there a way to make JavaScript bookmarklets show up as Mac OS X "Services", or otherwise execute JavaScript against the selected text in any Mac OS X app?

Comment: That won't work because bookmarklets depend on the JavaScript APIs provided by the browser. To do this, someone would need to write a third-party application that implements the browser APIs on top of the operating system. I don't think this can be done natively, without a separate application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can do it without rewriting the JavaScript to something like AppleScript. If you can do that, then in 10.6 Snow Leopard you can use Automator to create a new "service". Such service can, for example, work on selected text, such as [looking up something](http://www.macosxautomation.com/services/download/#InternetServices) on Wikipedia.